# Why is ST_GEOGFROMTEXT splitting this WKT Polygon in Multipolygon[Linestring, Polygon] in BIGQUERY?

Tags: google-bigquery

Unexpected Multipolygon when reading a WKT Polygon with `ST_GEOGFROMTEXT` in Bigquery

I am trying to load a polygon with `ST_GEOGFROMTEXT` as follow:

```sql
SELECT
  ST_GEOGFROMTEXT( 'POLYGON((-92.16479270559259 29.799188342837592,-92.1632862782261 29.8019483054684,-92.16115322688664 29.805828745544027,-92.16115613148023 29.80582346174626,-92.16540974352982 29.80586983686883,-92.16504927134031 29.801966532667507,-92.16479270559259 29.799188342837592))')
```

but I am getting the following result

```json
[{
  "f0_": "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(LINESTRING(-92.1611561314802 29.8058234617463, -92.1611532268866 29.805828745544), POLYGON((-92.1647927055926 29.7991883428376, -92.1632862782261 29.8019483054684, -92.1611561314802 29.8058234617463, -92.1654097435298 29.8058698368688, -92.1650492713403 29.8019665326675, -92.1647927055926 29.7991883428376)))"
}]
```

Using https://clydedacruz.github.io/openstreetmap-wkt-playground/, I could see that one of south-eastern side of the original polygon(triangle) is duplicated as a Linestring.

Could you help me understand what is going on, if it would be an issue in the original data?

Thanks in advance!